# How can I create a session-local cookie-aware HTTP client in Django?

Tags: python, django, http, cookies, urllib2

I'm using a web service backend to provide authentication to Django, and the get_user method must retain a cookie provided by the web service in order to associate with a session. Right now, I make my remote calls just by calling `urllib2.urlopen(myTargetService)` but this doesn't pass the cookie for the current session along.

I have created a session access middleware to store the session in the settings:

```
class SessionAccessMiddleware:

  def process_request(self, request):
    settings.current_session = request.session
```

So, I can access the request session in get_request and post_request, but I don't know how to have urllib2 remember my cookies in a session-specific way.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#examples are examples of doing exactly what you try to do with `urllib2` and `cookielib`. So according to docs you need to create `cookielib.CookieJar`, set cookie with correct data (from session), build an `opener` that uses your `CookieJar` and use it to fetch `yourTargetService`.

If `settings` in your middleware code means `from django.conf import settings` it's not good idea. Look at http://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-globals/ for a place where you can safely store request-wide data for access from somewhere where `request` object is unaccessible. Also, it would be probably good idea to write custom authentication backend and use it with `django.contrib.auth` - instead of rolling your own auth system from scratch - which is covered here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend .

Comment: I have, in fact, written a custom auth backend that is using these, so we're good with that.

django-globals doesn't seem to add much to the party; I'll consider it, if settings ever gives me trouble.

The thing I don't fully understand is the opener; how long can I keep those around? Can I create one and store _that_ in the session, for example?

Comment: I just checked - it appears you can not, sorry. opener and cookiejar objects are not pickleable(`UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle <type 'thread.lock'> objects`), so they can't be stored in sessions. But it is possible to pickle Cookie, as I just found out, so you can store it and add it to CookieJar (with `set_cookie`) every time you create an opener.